# Use case modeling help?

Tags: use-case

i would like to design my program

[alt text http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/331/helpq.jpg](http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/331/helpq.jpg)

what about relationships beetween use case?

this is my use case Is that correct??

Comment: Is what correct? That this is a use case?

Answer (score 2):

Your notation looks correct, but as Neil and Chris point out, there is very little to judge beyond that.  This is a good start in helping you organize your thoughts, understanding the large-grained use cases and involved actors.  Now, you need to proceed to break down the large-grained use cases into more-focused, finer-grained steps.  Textual use cases are good for this.  You might check out [Writing Effective Use Cases](http://www.amzn.com/dp/0201702258) by Alastair Cockburn for more information.

Once you have your steps reasonable defined, you can then flow into Activity Diagrams to more clearly show the logical flow, then on to Sequence Diagrams where you will really begin to flesh out the details of interaction.  Note that this is not a strict linear process.  Things you discover as your create each artifact likely will require you to revisit previous diagrams. As you proceed, however, your Use Cases, Class Diagrams, and other artifacts will evolve into a better representation of your target system.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is just a *[Use Case Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case_diagram)*.  Each of those bubbles can be broken out into proper use cases that identify the steps that the actors in the diagram perform to execute that use case.

For more about use cases, look here: http://www.parlezuml.com/tutorials/usecases.htm